# AG grid react framwork component cell render doesn't updae props

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am building a react functional component with an `AgGridReact`:

```
const DataGrid = (props) =>
{                                                                           
   const [gridRowData, setGridRowData] = useState([]);
   const [columnDefinition, setColumnDefinition] = useState([]);

useEffect(async () =>
    {
      if(props.name && props.name !== "")
      {
        ... get grid row data and column definition here according to props.name - working fine
      }
    },[props.name]);

let frameworkComponents = {
  customLoadingOverlay: LoadingOverlayTemplate,
      customNoRowsOverlay: UxDataGridCustomNoRows,
      editButton: params => <ViewAndDeleteSetting {...params}  
          openAddConfigurationsWindow={openAddConfigurationsWindow}
          onDeleteSetting={onDeleteSetting} />
};
.
.
.
const onDeleteSetting = async () =>
{
  console.log("ON DELETE AND NAME IS: " + props.name ); //PRINTS AN EMPTY STRING
   ...
}

return (
  <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={columnDefinition} 
            rowData={gridRowData} 
            frameworkComponents={frameworkComponents}/>
);
```

As you can see in the comment in `onDeleteSetting`, the name is empty when this callback is invoked. The rendering of the cell itself is fine and `ViewAndDeleteSetting` is indeed rendered, just it seems like it is being rendered only once and not every time the name changes. How can I cause the inner `ViewAndDeleteSetting` component to be re rendered with the most recent `frameworkComponents`?

Comment: your `onDeleteSetting` function reads the props of the agGrid component, so if you don't refresh the entire component with new props, the name printing would be the same.  i don't get exactly why you think the name would change, but maybe try to add arguments to the `onDeleteSetting` method form the `ViewAndDeleteSetting ` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I tried passing props to `ViewAndDeleteSetting`. If you want to pass prop to a cell rendered component, you shouldn't be doing it in `frameworkComponents`, but rather you need to do it in the column definition like this:

```
useEffect(() =>
{
  let columns = [{headerName: '', cellRenderer: 'editButton', width: 90, editable: false, 
                  cellRendererParams: {
                    openAddConfigurationsWindow: openAddConfigurationsWindow,
                    onDeleteSetting: onDeleteSetting
                }},
                .. other columns
                ]

  setColumnDefinition(columns);
},[props.name]);
```

The columns with the `cellRendererParams` do gets recreated in the `useEffect` when the name changes, and then the component can access this params regularly via its props

Comment: What version of ag-grid are you on?

Comment: @dsh just installed it today - 24.1.0

Comment: I don't think it is inherently impossible to pass props to a frameworkComponent. The issue was the reference was stale and not updating. I think you should be able to get around this with a getter such as `getFrameworkComponents(props)` that would dynamically compute on each render. But your solution achieves the same goal.

Comment: Even when I uses useMemo which basically implements a memoized getter like you suggested, it did not work